# ObservableList throwing NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx-8

I am adding some elements to an `ObservableList` in `JavaFX` and after adding some items I start getting `NullPointerException` for all the items I add. According to the `JavaDoc` the `add()` method throws `NullPointerException` when:

> NullPointerException - if the specified element is null and this list
>   does not permit null elements

But as you can see while I'm debugging my element is NOT null:

[image]

So why I am getting this `NullPointerException`?

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series$1.onChanged(XYChart.java:1525)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:72)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at sample.Main$1.handle(Main.java:115)
    at javafx.animation.AnimationTimer$AnimationTimerReceiver$1.run(AnimationTimer.java:58)
    at javafx.animation.AnimationTimer$AnimationTimerReceiver$1.run(AnimationTimer.java:56)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.animation.AnimationTimer$AnimationTimerReceiver.handle(AnimationTimer.java:56)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer.timePulseImpl(AbstractMasterTimer.java:359)
    at com.sun.scenario.animation.AbstractMasterTimer$MainLoop.run(AbstractMasterTimer.java:269)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:475)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:460)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit$13.run(QuantumToolkit.java:327)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Where `sample.Main$1.handle(Main.java:115)` is where I use the `add()` method.

**EDIT:**

It seems it only happens when I add the items inside things like `TimerTask()` or `AnimationTimer()`:

```
new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                for (XYChart.Data<Double, Double> data : fullDataQueue){
                    chartData.add(data);
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Otherwise I'm not getting this expection!

**EDIT 2:**

Ok I think I know what the problem is, here is the test code:

```
@Test
    public void testSeriesAddInAnimator(){
        // Data
        XYChart.Series<Double, Double> series = new XYChart.Series<>();
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<XYChart.Data<Double, Double>> fullDataQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Double, Double>> chartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        series.setData(chartData);

        // Start adding data
        final Random random = new Random();
        for(int n = 0; n < 10000; ++n){
            fullDataQueue.add(new XYChart.Data<>((double)n, random.nextDouble()));
        }

        new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                for (XYChart.Data<Double, Double> data : fullDataQueue){
                    chartData.add(data);
                }
                System.out.println("Stop!");
                //stop(); -> Uncomment this and we get no exception!
            }
        }.start();
        System.out.println("Done testSeriesAddInAnimator()!");
    }
```

This seems to happens if I re-add existing data in the Series. It's not [RT-37798](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37798) bug, but I think it's a bug too. If we comment `stop()` method inside `AnimationTimer` the same data will be re-added and we start getting all this `NullPointerException`.

The exception is in `XYChart.java` line 1525:

```
for(int i=c.getFrom(); i<c.getTo(); i++) {
                        getData().get(i).setSeries(Series.this);
                        // update linkedList Pointers for data in this series
                        if (begin == null) {
                            begin = getData().get(i);
                            begin.next = null;
                        } else {
                            if (i == 0) {
                                getData().get(0).next = begin;
                                begin = getData().get(0);
                            } else {
                                Data<X,Y> ptr = begin;
                                for (int j = 0; j < i -1 ; j++) {
                                    ptr = ptr.next;  // NPE HERE!!!!!
                                }
                                getData().get(i).next = ptr.next;
                                ptr.next = getData().get(i);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

But if I try to remove all items in the `ObservableList` and then add the ones I want I get the `NullPointerException` related to the bug you mentioned (RT-37798). So it seems I'm doomed, nothing I can do until they fix the bug.

Comment: Take a look at this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24359013/682840

Comment: So, again another JavaFX bug, I am considering switching to Swing again...

Comment: could be yet another variant of a bug I recently reported: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37798

Comment: can you show a small runnable example for me to test my assumption?

Comment: looking at the example (for the first time, sorry) - seems like that's different from your real-world context in that it adds the same instance of a data item more than once which isn't allowed (and doesn't make much sense :). Just saying ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that RT-37798 bug is solved in JDK 8u20 Build 21. Will submit the bug I am having to see If I can get some response (https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37824).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: careful: the fix in u20 could be just cosmetics - no longer throwing an NPE but the series' internal data structure might be out of sync with the list of data items

Comment: Yes I have read your comment so I decided to deploy my own chart library.  Thank you your help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it isn't `data`, but one of `data`s components that is `null`.

I couldn't find matching source code, but if you look at

```
javafx.scene.chart.XYChart$Series$1.onChanged(XYChart.java:1525)
```

Im confident that you find a dereferencing of a component of data.

Comment: if it's really related to https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37798 - as I suspect - there is nothing to do except waiting for the bug to be fixed :-( The deeper reason is a highly coupled design/implementation with back and forth callbacks all over the place and no clear (read: not documented) contract as to who is responsible for what when.